# I can see my SSD in my bios but it still won't let me install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I need help in stalling ubuntu it says sgx disabled by bios and will not boot

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; so we don't know what you're asking about. Ubuntu offers many ISO choices for its various products, with some having multiple ISO download choices which offer different installers; which did you try and use?  Why not tell us instead of making us guess?

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 lts

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Ubuntu *noble* has ISOs that use the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, `subiquity` & even `calamares` or `ubiquity` installer available; you need to be specific; however as *noble* is still only in *alpha*; it's off-topic here.  Yes issues exist for some installers (eg. `ubuntu-desktop-installer`) currently; but you're off-topic with that on this site.